# roget python script unkonwn bug

Tags: python, xml, nlp

Thank you very much, can you help me more. sorry it say I need more details say I can only say happy new yer to every one!and merry christmas .

```
import glob, lxml, re
from lxml import etree

# clean the input
def clean(l):
    l = l.replace('<size=-1>','')
    l = l.replace('</size>','')
    l = l.replace('<br>','')
    l = l.replace('&','&amp;')
    l = l.replace('"<"','&lt;')
    l = l.replace('">"','&gt;')
    return l.rstrip(',;\n') + '\n'

# get information from the xml
def headword(class_element):
    return re.sub('[0-9#\[\] ]','',class_element.find("headword").find("b").text)

def pos(pos_element):
    return re.sub('[.#]','',pos_element.find("b").text)

def words(paragraph_element):
    return set([word.strip() for i in paragraph_element 
           if not i.text is None 
           for word in i.text.split(',') 
           if not word == ' '
           ])

def index(fn,root):
    return re.sub('[/heads.txt]','',fn + ' ') + headword(root)

# helper generator:
def pospargen(c):
    for a,b in [c[x:x+2] for x in xrange(len(c)-1)]:
        if a.tag == 'pos' and b.tag == 'paragraph':
            yield [a,b]

# get list of [POS, [words,in,entry]]
def pos_words(c):
    return dict([[pos(a),words(b)] for a,b in pospargen(c)])

roget = {}

for fn in glob.glob("./heads/head*.txt"):
    with open(fn,'rb') as f:
        xml = ['<class>']+[clean(l) for l in f.readlines()]+['</class>']
        root = etree.fromstring(''.join(xml), parser=etree.XMLParser(encoding="windows-1252"))
        roget[index(fn,root)] = pos_words(root.getchildren())

parts_of_speech = ['INT', 'VB', 'ADJ', 'N']

from collections import defaultdict

reverse_roget = defaultdict(set)
for category in roget:
    for pos in parts_of_speech:
        if pos in roget[category]:
            for word in roget[category][pos]:
                reverse_roget[word + '_' + pos].add(category)

# INTERFACE COMMANDS
def categories(word,pos):
    "If you want to know which entries a word with a given part of speech occurs in"
    return reverse_roget[word + '_' + pos]

def common_categories(w1,w2,pos):
    "If you want to know which categories are shared by two words with a given part of speech"
    return reverse_roget[w1 + '_' + pos] & reverse_roget[w2 + '_' + pos]

def list_words(category,pos):
    "If you want to list the words with a given part of speech for an entry"
    return roget[category][pos]

def all_entries(word,pos):
    "If you want a list of lists, with each list containing the words for an entry"
    return [list_words(category,pos) for category in categories(word,pos)]

def shared_categories(l,pos):
    "If you want to know which categories are shared by a list of words with a given part of speech"
    return set.intersection(*[categories(w,pos) for w in l])

def pos(pos_element):
    return re.sub('[.#]','',pos_element.find("b").text
```

I have tried to revised the code following you suggestion.

```
w = "apple"
categories(word,pos(str(a)))
```

and the error is :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-242-77a24c5b4459> in <module>()
      1 w = "apple"
----> 2 categories(word,pos(str(a)))

<ipython-input-229-9d9e444ddd5a> in pos(pos_element)
     80 
     81 def pos(pos_element):
---> 82     return re.sub('[.#]','',pos_element.find("b").text)

AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Comment: `re.sub('[/Users/xccxken/Documents/roget/heads.txt]','',fn + ' ')` is clearly a problem: you're creating a character class between square brackets with ... an url!

Comment: "it doesn't work" isn't good enough. What's your exact problem? error message? stacktrace ?...

Comment: Sorry I have edited it, im new to python, but this is important to me, hope you can help me. And please tell me how to load the data file correctly.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`pos` is a function, defined here:

```
def pos(pos_element):
    return re.sub('[.#]','',pos_element.find("b").text)
```

you're trying to add strings with a function (the error message is explicit enough)

```
return reverse_roget[w1 + '_' + pos] & reverse_roget[w2 + '_' + pos]
```

Called from here:

```
common_categories(w1,w2,pos)
```

To get a string, you have to pass a parameter to `pos` (not sure what you would put instead of `a`):

```
common_categories(w1,w2,pos(a))
```

General advice: don't use the same names for parameters and function names (`pos` is a parameter in most of your functions and also a function) so you'll avoid mixups.

Comment: thanks! can you tell me the data type of parameter a? I tried list→'list' object has no attribute 'find'；int→'int' object has no attribute 'find'；

Comment: maybe an `lxml.etree.Element`